# Initialize an input (type="text") with the value of another input (type="hidden")?

Tags: javascript

Cannot use onload on the body tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<script>
    window.onload = function() {
        document.getElementById('id1').value = document.getElementById('id2').value;
    }
</script>
```